# Cyclic dependency in module 'X': X -> Y -> X, while using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods, circular-dependency

I have three projects, lets call them Tiger, Sheep & Grass and Cocoapods as my dependency tool. 
Until now, Tiger uses Sheep as a pod, and Sheep in turn uses Grass as a pod.

> Tiger -> Sheep -> Grass

Due to reasons outside the scope of this question, I now want to use Grass directly as a .framework in Sheep and continue using Sheep as a pod in Tiger.
So, I resorted to using vendored frameworks in Sheep's podspec as such:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Sheep/Frameworks/Grass.framework'
```

After pod-updating Tiger and trying to build it; in the file
*Pods/Sheep/Frameworks/Grass.framework/Headers/Grass.h* 
(Which is the umbrella header for Grass framework), I get the following error:

> Cyclic dependency in module 'Sheep': Sheep -> Grass -> Sheep
>   in front of the following statement `#import <Grass/HttpConstants.h>`

HttpConstants.h only exists in Grass. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Is this the wrong use case for vendored-frameworks or something else is the issue?

Comment: All 3 of them is pod with sources? Not packed .framework?

Comment: @Tj3n Tiger is the main project I'm developing, which uses Sheep as a pod with sources. Sheep directly uses Grass's packed .framework as a vendored framework.

Comment: Might be cruft in DerivedData. Try removing it and rebuild.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Tried, didn't work.